# How to enable jQuery Datatable Plugin with my HTML table?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am enabling [jQuery DataTable Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) like this and it is working:

```
$('#MyList').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 100
});
```

**Problem**: There is a delete row link with each row in table. This delete link is working with AJAX. When I click this link it delete the record and reload table content again But after AJAX request it shows the content but does not enable DataTable Plugin on html table.

It works fine if reload whole webpage but I want to reload only html table content.

How to reload my html table with datatable plugin after ajax requests ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `$('#MyList').dataTable( ...etc )` inside the success callback function of your AJAX request, after you set the new table content.

Comment: I am using General jQuery function for AJAX links and there are many datatable plugin tables. Is there any other way that I reload the MyDataTables.js(Contain all datatable initialization) after completing ajax request.

Comment: That sounds like a poor solution. Why don't you just put a common class name on all the tables so that you can activate them all with a single `$('.someclass').dataTable()`

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [`fnDeleteRow`](http://www.datatables.net/api) function to remove rows from the table. It will redraw the table after removing the row.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the datadatble initialization in the html result